# Which drop rates are boosted in Trailblazer Reloaded?

Tags: oldschool-runescape

In the Trailblazer Reloaded league, drop rates are boosted based on your relic tier. However, so far all I've been able to find out about this is that drops from "some sources" are more common, as stated in the passive.

[image: Passive Effects: Items from some sources will be 2x as common.]

Which drops are more common in the Trailblazer Reloaded league?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drops impacted by the drop rate modifier can be found in the "Drops" tab of the area info pages. In general, unique drops that cannot be crafted are boosted. For example, dragon crossbow limbs from all sources are boosted, but runite crossbow limbs are not.